# How do we integrate a function wrt a different variable

Tags: calculus, integration

For example, we have this func:

$$\int{x~ \sin (y) ~dx + y~\sin (x) ~dy}$$

how do we integrate wrt a different variable?

### EDIT

**Please read the following:**

We got a question in school as follows:

Find integral of following:
$$\int{y~dx + x~dy}$$

It was taught to us that $$d(xy) = y~dx + x~dy$$

So , $$\int{y~dx + x~dy} = \int{d(xy)} = \boxed{xy + C}$$

### **BUT**

if we do it by method that people told me here, it should be :

$$\int{y~dx + x~dy} = y\int{dx} + x\int{dy} = xy + xy + C = \boxed{2xy + C}$$

!!

Which is correct? Please enlighten me. I dont know calculus much. Also please recommend me a good reading on calculus and solving calculus problems.

Comment: If integrating with respect to x, you treat y as a constant and vice versa

Comment: write this as a sum of two integrals

Comment: I dont get it. will it become $${\sin(y)*\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\sin(x)*\dfrac{y^2}{2}}$$ ??

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Am i right above ^

Comment: @John please see upd8et ques

Comment: @TimKrul, derivative of $xy$ wrt $x$ gives $y'x +y$. I think you need to be careful with your notation here. Google stewart's Calculus textbook-plenty of exercises there.

Comment: @John: That is exactly what he got but in a different form. You are stating $\frac{d(xy)}{dx} = x \frac{dy}{dx} + y$ and he is stating $d(xy) = x\ dy\ +\ y\ dx$. I wouldn't recommend using the latter without knowledge of higher level mathematics though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what framework your teacher is using. If $x,y$ are variables that depend on some parameter $t$, then $\frac{d(xy)}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} y + x \frac{dy}{dt}$ by the product rule. We could **define** $\int x\ dy$ to mean an anti-derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$, specifically that $\frac{d(\int x\ dy)}{dy} = x$ for all values of $t$. Then we certainly get:

> $\frac{d(\int x\ dy + \int y\ dx)}{dt} = \frac{d(\int x\ dy)}{dt} + \frac{d(\int y\ dx)}{dt} = \frac{d(\int x\ dy)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{d(\int y\ dx)}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = x \frac{dy}{dt} + y \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d(xy)}{dt}$

And hence if the derivatives are defined everywhere we get:

> $\int x\ dy + \int y\ dx = xy + c$ (for all values of $t$) for some constant $c$ (with respect to $t$).

This also means that you cannot find what you asked for at the start of your question because $x,y$ are not defined. You must specify the dependence of $x,y$ on the parameter space before you can find the integral as defined in this framework.

Comment: actually it was a question on work, which is $W = \int{F\cdot d\vec{l}}$ THe force given was $\vec{F} = y\hat{i} + x\hat{j}$ and we had to use $d\vec{l} = dx \hat{i} + dy \hat{j}$   

Therefore it became: $$W = \int {y~dx + x~dy}$$. I think x and y are not independent as u said. how u got the last step from second last step in yellow box? Thanks!

Comment: @TimKrul: The rules used in order are sum rule, chain rule, derivative of integral, product rule.

Comment: @TimKrul: Yes your $x,y$ are tracing out a path in two dimensions and the unwritten parameter is time.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here comes from the notation $\int$ that may mean different things. If $\int y\,dx$ means *antiderivative* wrt $x$ and $y$ is just a constant that does not depend on $x$ then it is $xy+C$. However, your integral looks like
$$
\int y\,dx+x\,dy
$$
so it is more likely to be a [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) where (as @user21820 have mentioned) $x$ and $y$ are *not independent* variables. It is more common to use the integration path explicitly, i.e. to write 
$$
\int_\gamma y\,dx+x\,dy
$$
where the curve $\gamma$ is given, but in your case the differential form is [exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), i.e. it has a potential function $U(x,y)=xy$, so the integral becomes *path-independent* and $\gamma$ is omitted in the integral (a bit sloppy I would say).

P.S. the line integral
$$
\int x\sin(y)\,dx+y\sin(x)\,dy
$$
is *path-dependent*, because the differential form is not exact, so you can calculate it *only* along a particular curve $\gamma$ (which must be given).